# Dynamic jQuery with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to make a dynamic jQuery function with some help from Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress. This may not have something to do with the question, but I work in Wordpress with this plugin, anyway.

My code is like this:

```
<div id="restaurangmeny">

<h2>Vår meny</h2>

<? if( get_field('meny_for_restaurangen') ): ?>
<?php while( has_sub_field('meny_for_restaurangen') ): ?>

<div class="kategori">

<div class="kategorinamn" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?></div>

<div class="matratter" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>">

<? if( get_sub_field('matratter') ): ?>
<?php while( has_sub_field('matratter') ): ?>

<div class="matratt">

<div class="left">
<div class="namn"><?php the_sub_field('namn_pa_matratt'); ?></div>
<div class="beskrivning"><?php the_sub_field('beskrivning_av_matratten'); ?></div>
</div>

<div class="pris"><?php the_sub_field('pris_pa_matratten'); ?>:-</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div><!--#restaurangmeny-->
```

So what I want is when I click on the div called "kategorinamn" I want to div called "matratter" be shown or hidden. That's why I use same id for "kategorinamn" and "matratter" just because these 2 belong together.

Simply, if I click on 1 I want everything that got the same id (1) be shown. If I click on 2 I want everything that got the same id (2) be shown.

I don't know what dynamic jQuery like this is called, but I'm far away from being good with jQuery so that's why I'm asking.

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gwK6d/18/, but with jQuery only and that fit's my code above.

Comment: `id` values need to be unique in the DOM.  Re-using the same `id` is invalid markup and will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Element IDs are unique, using duplicate ids is a crime! seriously, use classes instead of IDs.

Comment: The ID's are unique, my php code above will make the id uniqe. If i declare the id to be one in first loop, I can declare same id to be two in the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Import jquery

2) Make sure you are not using the same id for multiple elements

3) Change this bit:

```
<div class="kategorinamn" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?></div>
<div class="matratter" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>">
```

To this:

```
<div class="kategorinamn" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>">
    <?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>
    <div class="matratter" id="<?php the_sub_field('namn_for_kategorin'); ?>">
</div>
```

4) Declare this function after load:

```
$(".kategorinamn").click(function(){
    $(this).children('.matratter').toggle();
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uRpc8/

Comment: I am sure you meant .kategorinamn and . matratter as those ids don't exist?

Comment: That will toggle every `.matratter` on the page.  We can see there will be several since that html is contained in a php `while` loop.  Use `$(this).next(".matratter").toggle()` to target just the related content.

Comment: gilly3: I guess that's what the OP needs - "Simply, if I click on 1 I want everything that got the same id (1) be shown."

Comment: @Henric (OP) Please provide more information on what you want exactly.

Comment: Hi! .kategorinamn is simply the class that should be clickable. I know basic jQuery and the function above doesn't solve my problem. My code above can generate 10 diffrent .matratter but with a uniqe id. It's a loop, that's why it should work dynamic. Otherwise I have to hardcode...

Comment: So, what's the problem with the above code? it should simply toggle as many .matratter as you want.

Comment: The problem is that it toogles all .matratter no matter which .kategorinamn I click on. Lets make it simple. If I click on a div called pizza only pizzas should appear, if i click on sallad, only sallad should appear. Same div class, yes but this is why I use unique ID's from my PHP in the loop.

Comment: Almost works, or your code works, but this was not was I was asking for. In this  way I have to change my div structure and that should not be necessary. The div "kategorinamn" is like where I type Pizza and the id of this is pizza. The div "matratter" is like diffrent sort of pizzas and still every "matratter" got Pizza as id. So If i click on Pizza all pizzas should be showned and so on.

Comment: Did it like you said. Work's but I can't make like an "arrow" in the object to be clickable instead of the whole div. Do you get the problem?

Comment: Try using something like: $(".kategorinamn > .arrow").click

Comment: And make sure you have a div with the arraw class unside of kategoriamn, next to matratter.